# SQL command in Rails to find all posts where current_user.id is in a string

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

In my app, there are a number of contributors to a post, with their id's stored in a string in the database. I'd like to find the total of posts where the user is listed as a contributor.
I've put the following in my ApplicationController (before_filter'ed):

```
 @posts = Post.find :all, :conditions => ['contributors like ?', current_user.id]
```

That code isn't working though. When I do @posts.size, it only offers up "0".

Evironment is Ruby 1.8.6 and Rails 2.3.8

Any thoughts as to how to format the SQL statement?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like:

```
 @posts = Post.find :all, :conditions => ["contributors like '%?%'", current_user.id]
```

Where `%` is a wildcard saying that anything can come before the user_id and anything can come after the user id.

However if you have the chance, I'd highly suggest making a many to many relationship instead of storing the id's in a string... such as:

```
User
----
id, username, etc 
Posts
--------
post_id, content, etc

Contributors
--------
post_id user_id
```

Comment: Ah, didn't think of creating another relationship! Will do that instead - thanks!